# Como colocar + de um domínio nesse código, diferentes referencias

Tags: php, http, referência

Ola, tenho um código que funciona como referencia.

Ou seja se a visita vier de dominio01.com, ele exibe: **COM REFERENCIA** se não exibe: **SEM REFERENCIA**

**Codigo:**

```html
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match('/dominio01.com/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { ?>
 COM REFERENCIA
<?php } else{ ?>
  SEM REFERENCIA
<?php }?>
```

Mas como colocar mais de um domínio ?

*Exemplo,* quando as referencias for de dominio01.com ou dominio02.com ou dominio03.com ou dominio03.com, exibir: **COM REFERENCIA**, quando não tiver enhumas dessas referencias exibir: **SEM REFERENCIA** ?

Comment: Tentei fazendo '/01.com/', '/02.com/' porem não funcionou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazer isso com `preg_match` não seria a melhor opção. Sugiro que você crie uma lista de domínios em forma de string, converta em array e verifique se algum valor da array está presente no REFERER com `strpos()`.

Cria uma lista com os domínios separados por vírgula:

```
$dominios = "dominio01.com, dominio02.com, dominio03.com";
```

Converta em array:

```
$doms_array = explode(',', $dominios);
```

Com um `foreach` você irá verificar se algum item da array está presente no REFERER. Criei também uma `$flag` com valor inicial `false`. Caso encontre alguma ocorrência, irá mudar para `true`:

```
$flag = false;
foreach($doms_array as $keys){
   if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], trim($keys))){
      $flag = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

E o `if` ficaria assim:

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $flag) { ?>
 COM REFERENCIA
<?php } else{ ?>
  SEM REFERENCIA
<?php }?>
```

**Código completo:**

```
<?php
$dominios = "dominio01.com, dominio02.com, dominio03.com";
$doms_array = explode(',', $dominios);
$flag = false;
foreach($doms_array as $keys){
   if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], trim($keys))){
      $flag = true;
      break;
   }
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $flag) { ?>
 COM REFERENCIA
<?php } else{ ?>
  SEM REFERENCIA
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tenha um problema na resposta do @dvd e do @Eduardo Bona, porque:

- `https://dominio01.com`
- `https://dominio01.com.meusite.com`
- `https://meusite.dominio01.com`

Todos esses são válidos para `dominio01.com`. Isso é, um subdomínio do meu site será validado como uma referencia. Se tenho posse de `aaa.com` poderei criar `dominio01.com.aaa.com`. Mesmo não sendo o `dominio01.com` serei considerado o `dominio01.com`, devido ao `strpos`. *Isto ignorando o fato do `Referer` ser manipulado de outras formas, como qualquer cabeçalho HTTP*

---

Acredito que isto deve ser substituto por `===`, assim deverá ser igual ao domínio, invalidando "o falso" subdomínio. Neste caso o `in_array` fará o trabalho.

```
$autorizados = ['dominio01.com', 'dominio02.com', 'dominio03.com'];
$atual = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);

$isReferencia = in_array($atual, $autorizados, true);
```

Depois para mostrar:

```
<?php if($isReferencia){ ?>
 COM REFERENCIA
<?php } else{ ?>
  SEM REFERENCIA
<?php }?>
```

> *PS: Não se não quão confiável é o `parse_url`.*